# python aiohttp slow response time

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am using the aiohttp client session to retrieve webpage asynchronously.

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    #async with session.get(url) as response:
    async with getattr(session,"get")(url) as response:
        return await response.text()


 async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:  # call 5
        html = await fetch(session, 'http://localhost:8081')
```

There are other async methods to prepare the data and massage the data.

The response is very slow. Enabled the async logging. It shows:

> Getting address info localhost:8081, type=
>   took 5016.262 ms: [(,
>   , 6, '',

Why does it take 5016ms?

Comment: try `$ pip install aiodns`

Comment: Try to make request using `requests` or `urllib3`. Is result the same?

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov it's much faster in a single request. But the concern is if it's under load, it would be slower.